# Redirect from Rails controller after Angular POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a normal Rails app (no SPA) and on one page only I'm using Angular.
At the end I'm sending a POST to the server with the form data (and it is working) and as the final step of the POST I'd like to redirect to another page.

Rails controller is like this:

```
def save
  data = params[:data]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :js => "window.location.href = '/products';" }
  end
end
```

But nothing is happening.

My Angular post is simple:

```
app.service('httpService', ['$http', function($http) {
  this.post = function(data) {
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : '/cart/save',
      data    : { data: data },
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });
  };
}]);
```

Calling service just like this, no promises:

```
this.save = function(ids) {
  httpService.post(ids);
};
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I have tried also change the mime-type to *'application/javascript'*, but no success:

```
app.service('httpService', ['$http', function($http) {
  this.post = function(data) {
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : '/cart/save',
      data    : { data: data },
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'}
    });
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't let the form submit be handled directly in Rails? so you don't perform an AJAX call but an actual POST request to the server

Comment: You mean the post done by form_tag, not by Angular? Because I'm selecting/unselecting values in Angular which are sent in the POST. Is there some way to pass angular values to "Rails" POST?

Comment: I'd have to see more code to understand exactly the problem. Ideally, you should be able to manipulate the form so that it still works as a HTML standard form submitting to Rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that the *$http* is sending an asynchronous request, thus the page cannot be redirected.

The solution was to send jQuery synchronous *$.ajax(..., async: false);*.